# High CPU consumption - PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, cpu

Although I saw several questions/answers about my problem, I could not solve it yet. I am trying to run a basic code from GitHub for training GAN. Although the code is working on GPU, the CPU usage is 100% (even more) during training.

https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-GAN/blob/master/implementations/wgan_gp/wgan_gp.py

In order to use my data, I added the following data loading code that I checked on PyTorch official documentation.

```
def Read_LMDB(root, classes):
    d1 = torchvision.datasets.LSUN(root=root, classes=classes, transform=transforms.Compose(
                [transforms.Resize((opt.img_size, opt.img_size)), transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))]))
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(d1, batch_size=opt.batch_size, shuffle=True)
    return dataloader

def Read_from_folder(folder_name):
    imagefolder = datasets.ImageFolder(folder_name,transform=transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.Resize(opt.img_size), transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))]))
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(imagefolder,batch_size=opt.batch_size,shuffle=True)
    return dataloader
```

However, still the same problem. It does not matter which functions I used, the CPU usage is 100%. Using such high CPU is not normal since the training is performed on GPU (and there is no problem with GPU usage. The GPU memory usage, utility, and the training speed are okay).

Could anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Best.

Comment: You assumption that 100% CPU usage is not normal is not correct, the CPU is busy moving data to the GPU, and some computations run on the CPU. GPUs are not magical that they will reduce load to 0% in the CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Of course, I know that. I did not say I expected that CPU usage should be zero or low since the model is trained on GPU. I am normally using TensorFlow and the CPU usage is not like in my question. There is a gap between CPU usage of TF and PyTorch in my system. So, I am wondering whether I did some mistake or not. Because I am not familiar with PyTorch so much. However, it seems that the usage is normal and the reason of gap between TF and PyTorch for me may be differences in complexity of the model, data, or another things. Thank you again!

Comment: i'm also suspicious that my pytorch model is erroneously using too much cpu. how could i go about to examine it properly?